# Widget tree exponentially grows from Bloc with Firestore stream

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-bloc

**Dependencies**

- Flutter_bloc package version 8.1.1
- equatable version 2.0.3
- cloud_firestore 3.4.4

**Problem**

After startup, the application correctly loads data from a single Google Firestore collection. In the application, the data is also updated correctly when updated in Firestore. However, the widget tree continues to grow by adding app.dart (contains `MultiBlocProvider`) exponentially. Eventually, the app becomes unresponsive and crashes with a stackoverflow.

[image]

**Code**

I'm removed all routes and the corresponding widgets except for the splash and home screen. The `HomeScreen` widget has been reduced to a simple `ListView` and `LoadingAnimationWidget`.

The issue still occurs, therefore I believe the problem is stemming from my Bloc implementation.

app.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => EstatesBloc(firestoreRepository: FirestoreRepository())..add(const LoadEstates()),
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color(0xff2C3639),
            appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
              backgroundColor: Color(0xff3F4E4F),
            ),
            primaryColor: Colors.deepPurple[200],
            brightness: Brightness.dark,
            visualDensity: const VisualDensity(horizontal: 2.0, vertical: 2.0),
            inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
              floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xffDCD7C9),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          home: const Splash(),
          // home: const HomeScreen(title: 'Home'),
          onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
            switch (settings.name) {
              case "main":
                return PageTransition(
                    child: const HomeScreen(),
                    childCurrent: this,
                    type: PageTransitionType.rightToLeftJoined);
              default:
                return null;
            }
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

homeScreen.dart

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Solace",
            style: GoogleFonts.sacramento(
                textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                letterSpacing: 1),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(child:
          BlocBuilder<EstatesBloc, EstatesState>(builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is EstatesInitial) {
          return LoadingAnimationWidget.discreteCircle(
            color: Colors.white,
            secondRingColor: const Color(0xffDCD7C9),
            thirdRingColor: const Color(0xff526061),
            size: 50,
          );
        }
        if (state is EstatesLoaded) {
          final currentEstates =
              state.estates.where((estate) => !estate.completed).toList();
          return Column(
              children: [ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: currentEstates.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Text(
                    currentEstates[index].address!,
                    style: GoogleFonts.sora(
                        textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium),
                  );
                },
              ),],
            );
          
        } else {
          return const Text('Something went wrong!');
        }
      })),
    );
  }
}
```

Firestore Repository

```
class FirestoreRepository {
  final estates = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('estates')
      .withConverter(
          fromFirestore: EstateModel.fromFirestore,
          toFirestore: (EstateModel estateModel, options) =>
              estateModel.toFirestore());

  Future<void> addEstate(EstateModel estateModel) {
    return estates
        .doc(estateModel.estateId)
        .set(estateModel)
        .catchError((error) => debugPrint("Failed to add estate: $error"));
  }

  Stream<List<EstateModel>> getAllEstates() {
    return estates
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList());
  }
}
```

estates_state.dart

```
part of 'estates_bloc.dart';

abstract class EstatesState extends Equatable {
  const EstatesState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class EstatesInitial extends EstatesState {}

class EstatesLoaded extends EstatesState {
  final List<EstateModel> estates;

  const EstatesLoaded({this.estates = const <EstateModel>[]});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [estates];
}
```

estates_event.dart

```
part of 'estates_bloc.dart';

abstract class EstatesEvent extends Equatable {
  const EstatesEvent();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class LoadEstates extends EstatesEvent {
  final List<EstateModel> estates;

  const LoadEstates({this.estates = const <EstateModel>[]});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [estates];
}

class UpdateEstates extends EstatesEvent {
  final List<EstateModel> estates;

  const UpdateEstates(this.estates);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [estates];
}
```

estates_bloc.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:estate_sale_biz/src/models/estateModel.dart';
import 'package:estate_sale_biz/src/repositories/firestore_repository.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

part 'estates_event.dart';
part 'estates_state.dart';

class EstatesBloc extends Bloc<EstatesEvent, EstatesState> {
  // Initialize firestore repo
  FirestoreRepository firestoreRepository = FirestoreRepository();

  // Declare private variables for firestore
  final FirestoreRepository _firestoreRepository;
  StreamSubscription? _firestoreSubscription;

  EstatesBloc({required FirestoreRepository firestoreRepository})
      : _firestoreRepository = firestoreRepository,
        super(EstatesInitial()) {
    on<LoadEstates>((event, emit) async {
      _firestoreSubscription?.cancel();
      _firestoreSubscription = _firestoreRepository
          .getAllEstates()
          .listen((estates) => add(UpdateEstates(estates)));
    });

    on<UpdateEstates>(
        (event, emit) async => emit(EstatesLoaded(estates: event.estates)));
  }

  @override
  void onChange(Change<EstatesState> change) {
    super.onChange(change);
    // debugPrint(change.toString(), wrapWidth: 1024);
    debugPrint(change.currentState.toString());
    debugPrint(change.nextState.toString());
  }
}
```

**Logs**

In the logs, I see the state continuously being updated. However, the `currentState` always starts as `EstatesInitial()`. So I believe this is telling me that the bloc is continuously being rebuilt?

```
I/flutter ( 8404): EstatesInitial()
I/flutter ( 8404): EstatesLoaded([EstateModel(15f004ef-775e-4f04-8e60-7da5c9b799d7, 2022-08-17 18:27:01.091208Z, 23456 g st, test, CO, Denver, 80021, 1234567890, re@re.com, retirement, 2022-08-31 06:00:00.000Z, 0, 0, false), EstateModel(1f369c28-307c-4763-86ca-37e418efc5f2, 2022-08-17 22:59:08.411310Z, 4866 Nile rd, Jean day, null, Greeley, 80601, 3037180380, hean@email.com, moving, 2022-09-14 06:00:00.000Z, 0, 0, false), EstateModel(39ef4466-8860-4b56-9328-ad6e59b2a122, 2022-08-17 23:14:02.181210Z, 4866 Nile rd, Jean day, null, Greeley, 80601, 3037180380, hean@email.com, moving, 2022-08-30 06:00:00.000Z, 0, 0, false), EstateModel(4f115dd3-a456-4bda-80f5-6ca88a54033d, 2022-08-17 18:31:08.316218Z, 456 Huron Rd., Sandra Bullock, CO, Westminster, 80021, 1234567890, gfr@re.com, moving, 2022-09-10 06:00:00.000Z, 0, 0, false), EstateModel(67b5e0e6-d86c-419c-8d5a-f44cf59df170, 2022-08-17 18:33:36.776599Z, 101 Rich Way, Damian Lewis 3, CO, Cherry Creek, 80201, 1234567890, ijk@re.com, downsizing, 2022-09-27 06:00:00.000Z, 22000, 26623,
I/flutter ( 8404): EstatesInitial()
I/flutter ( 8404): EstatesLoaded([EstateModel(15f004ef-775e-4f04-8e60-7da5c9b799d7, 2022-08-17 18:27:01.091208Z, 23456 g st, test, CO, Denver, 80021, 1234567890, re@re.com, retirement, 2022-08-31 06:00:00.000Z, 0, 0, false), EstateModel(1f369c28-307c-4763-86ca-37e418efc5f2, 2022-08-17 22:59:08.411310Z, 4866 Nile rd, Jean day, null, Greeley, 80601, 3037180380, hean@email.com, moving, 2022-09-14 06:00:00.000Z, 0, 0, false), EstateModel(39ef4466-8860-4b56-9328-ad6e59b2a122, 2022-08-17 23:14:02.181210Z, 4866 Nile rd, Jean day, null, Greeley, 80601, 3037180380, hean@email.com, moving, 2022-08-30 06:00:00.000Z, 0, 0, false), EstateModel(4f115dd3-a456-4bda-80f5-6ca88a54033d, 2022-08-17 18:31:08.316218Z, 456 Huron Rd., Sandra Bullock, CO, Westminster, 80021, 1234567890, gfr@re.com, moving, 2022-09-10 06:00:00.000Z, 0, 0, false), EstateModel(67b5e0e6-d86c-419c-8d5a-f44cf59df170, 2022-08-17 18:33:36.776599Z, 101 Rich Way, Damian Lewis 3, CO, Cherry Creek, 80201, 1234567890, ijk@re.com, downsizing, 2022-09-27 06:00:00.000Z, 22000, 26623,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being with `onGenerateRoute` within the app.dart file. I was using this approach because the `page_transition` package requires it. After the first route push using `Navigator.pushNamed(...)` the application would continuously be rebuilt and pushed to the widget tree stack.

I fixed the issue by using an imperative approach. Although, I am not sure if this was the best approach due to Flutter 2.0 moving to a declarative approach.

i.e.

```
initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    '/': (context) => const Splash(),
    '/main': (context) => const HomeScreen(),
    '/addEstate': (context) => const AddEstateScreen(),
},
```